# Django-Haystack-Whoosh is giving no results

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, whoosh

I'm trying to use Haystack-Whoosh for search in a Django application. I've implemented code same as mentioned in documentation page: [django-haystack documentaation](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html)  but still it is not working no search results were filtered.

Here is my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class Newcar(models.Model):
  car_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  carmodel = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  car_logo = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
  pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())

  def __str__(self):
     return self .car_name + '-' + self .carmodel
```

search_indexes.py

```
import datetime
from haystack import indexes
from car.models import Newcar


class NewcarIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
   text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
   car_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='car_name')
   carmodel = indexes.CharField(model_attr='carmodel')
   pub_date = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='pub_date')


   def get_model(self):
     return Newcar

   def index_queryset(self, using=None):

     return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

newcar_text.txt

```
{{ object.car_name }}
{{ object.carmodel }}
```

search.html

```
{% block content %}
<h2>Search</h2>

<form method="get" action=".">
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Search">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    {% if query %}
        <h3>Results</h3>

        {% for result in page.object_list %}
            <p>
                <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object.car_name }}</a>
            </p>
        {% empty %}
            <p>No results found.</p>
        {% endfor %}

        {% if page.has_previous or page.has_next %}
            <div>
                {% if page.has_previous %}<a href="?q={{ query }}&amp;page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">{% endif %}&laquo; Previous{% if page.has_previous %}</a>{% endif %}
                |
                {% if page.has_next %}<a href="?q={{ query }}&amp;page={{ page.next_page_number }}">{% endif %}Next &raquo;{% if page.has_next %}</a>{% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}

    {% endif %}
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

here is the error I'm getting:

```
  File "C:\Users\hp\ENV\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 88, in handle_error
super(ServerHandler, self).handle_error()
 File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
self.finish_response()
File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
 self.write(data)
File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
self.send_headers()
File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36  \Lib\socketserver.py", line 639, in process_request_thread
self.finish_request(request, client_address)
 File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
 File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
self.handle()
 File "C:\Users\hp\ENV\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 155, in handle
handler.run(self.server.get_app())
 File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
self.close()
 File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: the `error message` link needs to be included in this question somehow for future reference in case the link disappears.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @Edward Thankyou, I've edited the question.